# GetAllWithChildren() performance issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I used [SQLite-Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions)
 in the following code to retrieve 1000 rows with their children relationships from an Sqlite database:

```
var list =
SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations.GetAllWithChildren<DataModel>(connection);
```

**The problem is that the performance is awkward.** Because `GetAllWithChildren()` returns a List not an Enumerable. Does exist any way to load the records in to an Enumerable using Sqlite.net extensions?

I now use `Table()` method from [Sqlite.net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), loads the fetched rows in to the Enumerable but I dont want to use it because it does not understand the relationships and does not load the children entities at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetAllWithChildren` suffers from the [`N+1` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue), and in your specific scenario this performs specially bad. It's not clear in your question what you're trying, but you could try these solutions:

#### Use the `filter`parameter in `GetAllWithChildren`:

Instead of loading all the objects to memory and then filter, you can use the `filter` property, that internally performs a `Table<T>().Where(filter)` query, and SQLite-Net will convert to a `SELECT-WHERE` clause, so it's very efficient:

```
var list = connection.GetAllWithChildren<DataModel>(d => d.Name == "Jason");
```

#### Perform the query and then load the relationships

If you look at the [`GetAllWithChildren` code](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/9b65308fa6a95cbc9fd9dce8c222efa5c1b8ff7b/SQLiteNetExtensions/Extensions/ReadOperations.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#ReadOperations.cs-47) you'll realize that it just performs the query and **then** loads the existing relationships. You can do that by yourself to avoid automatically loading unwanted relationships:

```
// Load elements from database
var list = connection.Table<DataModel>().Where(d => d.Name == "Jason").toList();
// Iterate elements and load relationships
foreach (DataModel element in list) {
    connection.GetChildren(element, recursive = false);
}
```

#### Load relationships manually

To completely workaround the *N+1 problem* you can manually fetch relationships using a `Contains` filter with the foreign keys. This highly depends on you entity model, but would look like this:

```
// Load elements from database
var list = connection.Table<DataModel>().Where(d => d.Name == "Jason").toList();
// Get list of dependency IDs
var dependencyIds = list.Select(d => d.DependencyId).toList();
// Load all dependencies from database on a single query
var dependencies = connection.Table<Dependency>.Where(d => dependencyIds.Contains(d.Id)).ToList();
// Assign relationships back to the elements
foreach (DataModel element in list) {
    element.Dependency = dependencies.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == element.DependencyId);
}
```

This solution solves the N+1 problem, because it performs only two database queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But using `Table()` in your solutions we are limited to filter only on the properties of the main entity. What should I do if I want to filter on children properties? Do I have to join the tables manually in sql?

Comment: That would be the most efficient way, yes. Converting your 'in-memory' filters to SQL 'where' statements is usually much more efficient. Your case is even worse because of the N+1 problem when loading the entity tree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, actually your thing is not as useful as I thought yesterday. I prefer to write all queries myself and care the application size instead of using a package just to implement a simple data List without any paging and practical search and real Relational Mapping. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Take into account that filtering on relationship properties is not supported on many server-side ORM. However, if you think that the library can be improved, feel free to open a issue, or even better, submit a pull request.

Comment: Except if your DB does not consist of 2 tables, but dozens...then implementing "Load relationships manually" is basically impossible...

Answer (score 0):

### Another method to load relationships manually

Imagine we have these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> children { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Id.Equals(((BaseModel) obj).Id);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Child
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Hint these classes have one-to-many relation. Then inner join between them would be:

```
        var parents = databaseSync.Table<Parent>().ToList();
        var children = databaseSync.Table<Child>().ToList();

        List<Parent> parentsWithChildren = parents.GroupJoin(children, parent => parent.Id, child => child.ParentId,
            (parent, children1) =>
            {
                parent.children = children1.ToList();
                return parent;
            }).Where(parent => parent.children.Any()).ToList();
```